# Not being able to add button click event in c#

Tags: c#

I have this code which generates me some buttons from a foreach loop.

```
Controls.Button btn = new Controls.Button();
btn.button1.Text = "Details";
btn.Location = new Point(200, cnt);
panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

When I try this after it doesn't work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? Is `button1` defined?

Comment: well yes i think so, it appears in my form

Comment: as already answered, you need to subscribe to the buttonClicked-Event. You handle the event, therefore your method (button1_Click) is an eventhandler. You can easily recognize this when looking at the parameters, these are VERY common for eventhandlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Controls.Button btn = new Controls.Button();
btn.ID= "ID" + counter;
btn.button1.Text = "Details";
btn.Location = new Point(200, cnt);
btn.Click += button1_Click;
panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

You should write it like this ! Be aware in this case all of your button in foreach method will have same Click event handler. It will be good to have ID + counter of the buttons to make differnce about them.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     string id= ((Button)sender).ID;
     if(id == "value")
     {
     }
     else if(id == "another value")
     {
         MessageBox.Show("");
     }
}
```

Comment: @Perf The problem is that you have either not shared all the code or you don't have concept of event handling

Comment: The butten is a UserControl item, so should i change it in the UserControl?